# Drawing and computing tangents in R

Tags: r

I have two questions with regard to tangents.

(1) Is there an "easy" way to draw multiple tangents or do I have to copy and paste the function a couple of time?

(2) Is there a way to let R compute the tangent?

I have the following function:

```
Q <- 10
C <- 15
S <- seq(0,12,.1)

A <- function(S) (Q^2)/S
B <- function(S) (C/1)-(2*S)

plot(S, A(S), type="l", col="blue", ylim=c(0,30) ,ylab = "A")
lines(S, B(S), col="red")
```

ad 1) I would like to draw 5 to 8 (not sure what the "appropriate" number would be in order for the graphic to look nice) tangents between the blue and the red function.

ad 2) I have computed the function of the tangent by hand:

```
B <- function(S) (28.28/1)-(2*S)
```

Is there a way to let R do this?

Comment: I’m guessing that you need to apply R’s ability to do differentiation to some coordinate geometry via the ‘abline’ function.

Comment: What exactly do you mean?

Comment: When I wrote that comment I was assuming that you meant "tangent" as a line that touches a curve at one point, but that appears to be something different than what you mean by that word. So I need to ask instead: What do _you_ mean?

Comment: I am sorry! You are right. I had something in my but I did not express myself clearly. What I want to show is that one can draw many different straight lines between the "red" and "blue" functions. By doing so, one will finally end up being a tangent. So my first question was meant to ask if there is a way of drawing many different straight lines at a time or do I have to copy and paste the function many times in order to have those different straight lines. Sorry again that I did not express myself clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps I understand now. I will rewrite your tangent-ized version of B to include an offset:

```
 B2 <- function(S) (28.28/1)-(2*S+z)
```

Now any invocation of that function will attempt to find z in its environment so we can use teh `$<-` function to sequentially modify its environment prior to invocation with the `curve` function using `add=TRUE` so the existing plot gets updated:

```
for(offset in seq(8, 0, by=-2) ){ environment(B2)$z=offset ; curve(B2, add=TRUE)}
```

Creates 5 lines below or at the tangent line you offered.

[image]